# Redireccionar a URL en java REST? o no redireccionar?

Tags: java, rest

Entiendo que Rest es una arquitectura entre un servidor y cliente, httpRequest y httpResponse, es el tema que estamos viendo en un curso que estoy haciendo. El problema es que estoy haciendo en Rest un código que inserta datos por medio de parámetros @FormParam en una base de datos, el cual funciona excelente, sin embargo, una vez que se envían los datos quiero que se redireccione a otra página, por ejemplo la de inicio. pero acá viene mi pregunta, en mi curso me dicen que no, que tengo que hacer algo con html o javascript y que el cliente tome decisiones, no entiendo eso realmente, estoy tan acostumbrado a los servlets y el RequestDispatcher y que me redireccione que esta parte no la entiendo.

He seguido recomendaciones como usar URi o httpResponse.sendRelocation(); pero dicen que va contra la filosofía de REST.

Les dejo mi código para que vean, estoy trabado realmente por la costumbre de la redirección, cómo hago para aplicar eso que dicen que el cliente tome decisiones ???.
Como verán el método Devuelve un String, sin embargo pensé en cambiar el método por un Response, pero es lógico eso? está mal esa práctica que quiero hacer en Rest? que es eso de que cliente toma decisiones.? y cómo lo aplico?

```
package aeropuerto_empleados;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


import data_access_object.ConexionAeropuerto;



//Acá tengo que poner algún path? porque me está tirando error http 404
public class Administradores {

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("/administradores")
public String insertarEmpleado(@FormParam("nombre") String nombre , @FormParam("apellido") String apellido, @FormParam("usuario") String usuario, @FormParam("pass") String pass, @FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("direccion") String direccion){

    try
        {

        ConexionAeropuerto c= new ConexionAeropuerto();
        Connection con= c.connectarAhora();

        if(con!=null)
                {
                    Statement st;
                    st=con.createStatement();
                    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO administradores(nombre,apellido,usuario,pass,email,direccion) VALUES('"+nombre+"','"+apellido+"','"+usuario+"','"+pass+"','"+email+"','"+direccion+"')");
                    st.close();
                    System.out.println("Funciona el try and catch");


                    //Qué codigo puedo escribir acá para que me redireccione al index.jsp una vez realizada la consulta??? debe ser simple imagino. 
                    //Response.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } 
        else
                {
                    System.out.println("Algo Salió mal no se pudo insertar los datos");
                }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return "<html>" + "<body><h3>" + "El nombre del empleado es: "  + usuario  + direccion + "<br>"+ "El apellido del empleado es: " + pass + "</h3></body>" + "</html>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que te han dicho es correcto. La tecnología REST se orienta a recursos utilizando http como protocolo y las respuestas siempre son valores de estado de http (200, 201, 400,...). Eso no quita que puedas utilizar las cabeceras para enviar información adicional (apikeys...).

En relación a tu ejemplo, solo comentarte que las url, siguiendo la filosofía REST, no está bien construidas ya que, como te comentaba antes, deben representar recursos y los métodos http son los que representan las acciones con esos recursos. Por lo tanto, la url para tu servicio debería ser `.../administradores/` y al hacer un POST sobre el te crea un administrador y al hacer, por ejemplo, un GET sobre `.../administradores/{keyadministrador}`te devolvería el administrador correspondiente a ese identificador. Además, para el intercambio de la información se usa JSON o XML, no se suele devolver nunca HTML.

Dicho esto, en cuanto al tema de la redirección, con una orientación basada en recursos, si tu invocas un endpoint con POST (`.../administrador`) el servicio, después de realizar la operación correspondiente, debería devolver un código 201. Eso le indica al cliente que el recurso se ha creado. Y es responsabilidad del cliente decidir que hacer después. En este caso redirigir a otra página. Ten en cuenta que esto es propio ya de cada implementación, habrá veces que quieras redirigir, otras solo mostrar un mensaje de que la operación se ha realizado correctamente.... eso depende de lo que el que está consumiendo tu api rest quiera hacer después.

Espero haberte aclarado un poco las cosas con este tostón :)

Comment: Hola  @fernando-forcén me super sirve tu información, una de las cosas que vos me decís es que cambie el path extra y que trabaje sobre un mismo path? "Path("/insertarAdministrador")" éste de acá? mirá el código, ésa linea va a estar comentada. Intenté trabjar sobre un mismo path principal ejemplo páth("/administradores"), sin embargo al momento de correr el servidor el mismo me tiraba errores y no arrancaba. Fijate si lo que cambié está bien.

Comment: Hola, efectivamente. El cambio está bien realizado pero no en el sitio correcto. Lo tienes que poner justo encima del método `insertarEmpleado` (tal y como lo tenías antes pero con la ruta nueva)

Comment: Ahí lo cambié de lugar lo puse encima de insertarEmpleado(), sin embargo no sé si lo hice bien. Había entendido que la linea path("/insertarAdminstrador") habia que borrarla, y laburar sólo con con la principal. no sé si estoy en lo correcto.

Comment: No, es que esas lineas deberían quedar como:

public class Administradores {

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("/administradores")
public String insertarEmpleado(@FormParam("nombre") String nombre , @FormParam("apellido") String apellido, @FormParam("usuario") String usuario, @FormParam("pass") String pass, @FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("direccion") String direccion){

Comment: ahora lo modifico

Comment: Probandolo en el eclipse me dice que no encuentrar la página, tengo que poner algo arriba del "public class Administradores"{} ahi modifico y te muestro lo que hice

Comment: Ten en cuenta que lo que antes hacías en `/administradores/insertarAdministrador`, ahora lo tienes que hacer solo en `/administradores` que ahora estas identificando recursos y no acciones.

Comment: Te entiendo, pero arriba de public class Administradores{} tengo que poner algo? pregunto porque cuando lo corro dice no encontrar la página me tira http 404, te muestro en el origianl que cambie

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54932/discussion-between-fernando-forcen-and-berlot83).

Answer (score 0):

Después de casi 8 meses de formulada por mi esta pregunta pretendo agregar algunos datos que no coloqué en la pregunta misma, la respuesta de @fernando-forcén fue muy clara y me quitó todas la dudas sobre REST. Sin embargo hay unos detalles que quiero aclarar con respecto a mi pregunta.

1) El código de la pregunta se hace en base a jersey 1.19 si no me falla la memoria.

2) Nombré clases como HttpRequest, HttpResponse y RequestDispatcher porque en ése momento estaba muy al tanto Servlets, sin embargo nada tienen que ver con Rest por lo que al momento tengo entendido.

3) En el código de insercción a DB utilicé un Statement para realizar una la consulta, contrario a lo que dice la Documentación oficial de Oracle la cual recomienda utilizar PreparedStatement, funcionar me funcionaba, pero no era lo recomendado. Hoy en día esas cosas las tengo un poco más claras, espero que esta segunda aclaración ayude a alguien.

4) Como dijo Fernando Forcén Rest debería devolver la respuesta en xml o json, en mi caso comencé por la clase Jackson 2.8.0 ya que es la más popular, sin embargo con el tiempo me incliné por Gson ya que a mi entender es más simple y funciona espectacular.